# Unable to close closable tabs and to activate tabs

Tags: javascript, extjs

I made a [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/216n) which demonstrates these issues. The first issue is that it is impossible to close closable tabs in a TabBar. The code is as simple as:

```
Ext.create("Ext.tab.Bar",{
   renderTo: "one",
   items:[{"text":"One","closable":true},{"text":"Two","closable":true}]
});
```

Documentation says, that

> closable : Boolean bindable
>
> True to make the Tab closable and display the close icon

So, this property is not only about this close icon, but also about this behaviour to be closed.

The second issue I face is that it is impossible to activate tabs added to a tabpanel through a tabbar. The code is also very simple:

```
Ext.create("Ext.tab.Panel",{
    renderTo: "two",
    id: "test2",
    items:[{"title":"One","closable":true},{"title":"Two","closable":true}],
    listeners: {
        render: function () {
            this.getTabBar().add({"text":"Three"});
        }
    }
});
```

Just try to activate this last tab and you will fail. And if you set `active` property on this tab, then you won't be able to deactivate this tab. So, how can we fix all this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TabBar is used internally by a Ext.tab.Panel and typically should not
>   need to be created manually.

The tabbar's implementation relies on the fact that it is a part of a tabpanel. If we dig in it's source, we will see that in the "[closeTab](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Bar.js-3.html#Ext.tab.Bar-method-closeTab)" method implementation it checks if there is an underlying card to close:

```
if (tabPanel && card) {...
```

Related to the second behavior, if you will check out the "doActivateTab" method implementation, also in the tabbar source code, this is what you will see:

```
doActivateTab: function(tab) {
    var tabPanel = this.tabPanel;

    if (tabPanel) {
        // TabPanel will call setActiveTab of the TabBar 
        if (!tab.disabled) {
            tabPanel.setActiveTab(tab.card);
        }
    } else {
        this.setActiveTab(tab);
    }
}
```

So if there is no tabpanel, it will just activate the tab, if there is, it will call the tabpanel's "[setActiveTab](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/src/Panel.js-4.html#Ext.tab.Panel-method-setActiveTab)", that if it doesn't find a card attached to the tab-to-be-activated, activates the previous tab.

You should not add directly to the tabbar, instead add to the tabpanel:

```
this.add({"title":"Three"});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2197).  Seems like setactivetab needs to be after render.